# How to cancel View.OnDragListener in android during dragging Operation?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

Im using `view.startDrag()` to start dragging operation. While dragging, events are received in `OnDragListener`. Also im using `DragShadowBuilder` to show the last image of `View B` while dragging.

Is there a way to stop or cancel or abort dragging from some external events or operation? for example, there are 2 view, `View A` and `View B`, i'm dragging `View B` over `View A`. While dragging, due to some external event or operation, i want to cancel dragging operations or cancel `OnDragListener` (without removing my finger from the `view B`).

Code Snippet for `DragShadowBuilder`:

```
DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new DragShadowBuilder(view) {
    @Override
    public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(b, 0, 0, new Paint());
        super.onDrawShadow(canvas);
    }
};
boolean dragSuccess = false;
dragSuccess = view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
```

Code Snippet for `OnDragListener`:

```
private final class ViewDragListener implements OnDragListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                 log("ACTION_DRAG_STARTED");
                 break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                 log("ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED");
                 break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                 log("ACTION_DRAG_EXITED");
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                 log("ACTION_DROP");
                 mX = (int) event.getX();
                 mY = (int)event.getY();
                 break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                 log("ACTION_DRAG_ENDED");
                 //Doing some cleanup operations.
                 break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                 log("ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION");
                 break;
            default:
                 break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any trick for this. I tried sending a motion event of ACTION_UP and it did nothing. As long as the user's finger is held down, there's no interrupting the event hierarchy, it seems. I found nothing to help with a google search.

I just set a global and waited until the drag ended, then proceeded.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#cancelDragAndDrop()

?

> cancelDragAndDrop Added in API level 24
>
> public final void cancelDragAndDrop () Cancels an ongoing drag and
> drop operation.
>
> A DragEvent object with DragEvent.getAction() value of
> DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED and DragEvent.getResult() value of false
> will be sent to every View that received DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED
> even if they are not currently visible.
>
> This method can be called on any View in the same window as the View
> on which startDragAndDrop was called.